# I want to read what inside this form

Tags: java, string, split, token, stringtokenizer

I have this line entered by the user :

```
  Join <person> <department>
```

I want my program to read what between the <>.
so that my program will invoke the Join method. With two arguments person and department.

For example:
       Join  
call method:

```
  Join("jhon mary","Customer Service");
```

Join method defined as :

```
  public boolean Join(String name, String department){...}
```

Comment: [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: @KickButtowski Link me up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op fails to do any research and show any effort

Comment: @KickButtowski agreed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: String splitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211190/java-string-splitting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work, but you should refine it in case the user doesn't input something valid.

```
String input = ...;
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
String name = tokens[1];
String department = tokens[2];

Join(name, department);
```

Again, I strongly encourage you to refine this and only use it as a base. The user could enter too many or too few arguments